# Do long running operations lock redis?

Tags: redis

In Redis, some operations such as [`SINTERSTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/sinterstore) have

> **Time complexity:** O(N*M) worst case where N is the cardinality of the smallest set and M is the number of sets.

In my use case, I expect to be comparing sets of upwards of 15,000 items each. Performing an N*M operation on these sets would be O(30,000). There is no time requirement for the operation, meaning I don't care how long it takes. My question is whether my Redis will lock while this calculation is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "Yes", because Redis is based on a single threaded architecture.

The non-simple answer is "it depends" - if you shard your Redis in an optimized manner, only the shard that does this complex operation is blocked, the other shards are not.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is single-threaded.  It doesn't lock anything, but it won't process any other commands until that one finishes.  So it's as if Redis were locked, which I think is what you meant.

See also: [Locking and Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650232/locking-and-redis)